# Change label from 2 different Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I'm trying to change labels when pressing on a button on 2 different windowsForms.

If I open the second form I can change it easy but I cant figure out how to change data on a Form that's already open. I keep getting `NullRefferenceExecption`.

This is the code i use in my buttons on `Form1` and `Form2`:

```
public Form2 m_Form2;

m_Form2 = new Form2();
m_Form2.Show();
m_Form2.label1.Text = "pressed on form 1";
```

And:

```
public Form1 m_Form1;

m_Form1.label1.Text = "pressed on form 2";
```

Comment: Which line gives you the `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: You have to access the `label1` property on an *instance* of one of the forms. You cannot simply modify the property on the *type*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a reference of `Form1` to `Form2`, for example via constructor:

```
public Form2 m_Form2;
m_Form2 = new Form2(this);
m_Form2.Show();
```

in Form 2:

```
public Form2(Form1 form1)
{
    this.m_Form1 = form1;
}

public Form1 m_Form1;
```

somewhere:

```
m_Form1.label1.Text = "pressed on form 2";
```

But `label1` needs to be public or you need to provide a public property that get/sets `label1`'s Text.

Answer (score 1):

Keep controls private, so they can be accessed only from the form created. Use a form`s reference to access to some form. 
I will show you on a button press (in each of the forms) how to pass data from form to form simplier:

```
class Form1
{
    Form2 f2;
    private void buttonOpenForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        f2 = new Form2(this);
        f2.Show();
    }

    private void SayHiOnForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        if(f2 != null)
           f2.DataFromForm2("Hello from form 1.");
        else
           MessageBox.Show("Form2 is not yet opened.");
    }

    public void DataFromForm2(stirng message)
    {
        this.label1.Text = message;
    }
}

//on form2:
class Form2
{
    Form1 f1;
    public Form2(Form1 _f1)
    {
        InitilaizeComponent();
        this.f1 = _f1;
    }

    private void SayHiOnForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        f1.DataFromForm2("Hello from form 2.");
    }

    public void DataFromForm1(stirng message)
    {
        this.label1.Text = message;
    }
}
```

You can even use events if you want to. Its more neet, but this will work too.